# Is it a good programming practice to have a signal with 3 or more parameters

Tags: c++, qt4, qml

I have a requirement in my project that i have to get the values of around 10 to 15 variables in to my qml file from a cpp file which is present in another application. The only communication between the two applications is through a intermediate Plugin. Is there any better approach other than calling a Q_INVOKABLE method in the plugin from the qml , then raising a signal over there, catching the signal in the other application, then set the variables in the plugin, from the plugin again send the data to the qml file. As i have more than 10 variables to be get from the other application, what is the best way to do it?...Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to pass more than _X_ number of parameters stuff them into a `struct`. In this case you've got more than _X_ where _X_ is a reasonable number.

Comment: Doesn't it degrades the performance?

Comment: pass this train via structure

Comment: Won't know until you profile it but IMHO it's doubtful since you're already passing around 10 flippin parameters . I do wonder how many copies are being made throughout the entire call frame.

Comment: Depending on how big each of the variables are, you might improve performance by putting them into a struct, new it up, and pass a shared pointer.  Or maybe not; that's what profiling is for.  Alternately (ignoring threading issues), put the data into a shared variable, give both sides a reference to it, then set the variable in one class and emit a signal to read the data from the other class.  Note that this loses the ability to have multiple data queued, but for some types of data you only want the latest anyway.